# InvalidCastException error for Naudio's MMDeviceEnumerator

Tags: exception, naudio

Whenever I try to create a new MMDeviceEnumerator I get an error

```
MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
```

gives me

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in NAudio.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'MMDeviceEnumerator' to type 'NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces.MMDeviceEnumeratorComObject'.
```

I'm using VS Community 2015, Naudio 1.7.3, on Windows 7 64 bit. Does anyone have a solution to this? NAudio's Midi API seems to work fine.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?